# Boost: how to convert string like "true" or "1" to bool true and "0" or "false" to bool false?

Tags: c++, string, boost, boolean

Is  `boost::lexical_cast<bool, std::string>( string );` only option or there are faster ways to do such thing, will it work on `True` string, wll it work on `1` string, will it work on `TRUE` string?

(because to me it gives `bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target` error)

Comment: Faster? How slow is what you're comparing against?

Comment: Mainly I wonder if it will work on such strings in general?

Comment: What exactly is your performance bottleneck?

Comment: Worry about *correct* before considering *fast*. What makes you think that `boost::lexical_cast` can convert "true" to true?

[It doesn't.](http://ideone.com/ilWhr)

Answer (score 5):

One fast way to do it is to have a pre-initialized `map<string,bool>` with all the acceptable strings along with their boolean equivalents. Then it's just a matter of doing `find`.